# Does javascript's "document.title" method get indexed by search engines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using javascript / jQuery to dynamically set the html `<title>` attribute of some pages. The code I'm using is placed well after the `<head>` tag using `$(document).ready(...)`.

My code is essentially `document.title = "Some page name";` which works well, but obviously only with javascript enabled.

So I was wondering if Google would/could read a dynamically set page `<title>` and use it to index the page?

Thanks

Comment: [This would seem to suggest not](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?rd=1): _"make sure every page on your site has a title specified in the <title> tag"_

Comment: This question is probably not on-topic for Stack Overflow, since it asks about the behavior of search engine services, rather than a technical programming concern like a compilation or algorithmic issue. This might be on topic for [Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). If you choose to post there (after checking to see if your question has not already been answered there), be sure to delete this question. You could also flag your own question for moderator attention and request migration.

Comment: You may wish to have a look at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/58915/49656.

Comment: Thanks. From what I can gather reading the link you provided it seems that in a word ... No. Javascript modified tags like `<title>` and `<h1>` seem to be ignored by Google. A key quote from that article reads _"You need core SEO factors hard-coded if you want Google to reward you for them"_. So that pretty much answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, **it might**. We are developing a website that adds a small price tag before the page's `<title>` using JavaScript and it appears on Google's search results. Right now I'm trying to find a way to fix this.

[image]